# How to query a specific enum value with where condition to Firestore

Tags: swift, google-cloud-firestore

I have this enum:

```
enum washingPowderState: Codable {
    case notOpen, open, used
}
```

When storing the field in Firestore it looks like this:

[image: Firestore screenshot]

When opening the field it looks like this (empty)
[Updated and expanded](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QheCX.png)

I then try to access documents where this field is e.g. 'notOpen' with code like this:

```
db.collection(K.NoSQLCollections.washingPowder)
    .whereField("roles.\(uid)", isEqualTo: K.Roles.owner)
    .whereField("status.notOpen", isEqualTo: "")
    .getDocuments { querySnapshot, err in .... }
```

I do however not get any results back even though I have documents with that value. If I remove the second .whereField query I get all documents back without any problems.
I can of course filter out this in the code, but I would like to understand how to get the correct content directly from the query. Anyone who can guide me?

Comment: Your `'notOpen` seems to be stored as a map field. If you click the ▶ in front of `notOpen`, what does it show?

Comment: Instead of Codable use String.

Comment: Please edit your question and add the information Frank asked for, and please also respond using @.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen - it is a correct assumption. The 'notOpen' seems to be stored as a map field. I have used `collectionRef.addDocument(from: myStruct)` when adding the document to Firestore.

Comment: @loremipsum - thanks, I changed the enum to String protocol and it works much better as it is stored as String instead of map.